# get menu id using its name

Tags: menus, id

I have a menu name `Social Network`. I want to get the menus ID. I tried the following, but didn't succeed.

```
  global $wpdb;
$menu_slug = 'social-network';
$menu_id = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT TERM_ID
    FROM $wpdb->wp_terms
    WHERE name = ".$menu_slug."
    "
);
echo $menu_id;
```

Comment: What exactly is inside `$args`?

Answer (score 8):

You can use the function get_term_by and use 'name' in the field param.

```
<?php get_term_by( $field, $value, $taxonomy, $output, $filter ) ?>
```

Example:

```
$term = get_term_by('name', 'Social Network', 'nav_menu');
$menu_id = $term->term_id;
```

Here is the link to the codex page:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_term_by

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 4):

All you need is `get_terms()`

### Let's write `wp_menu_id_by_name( $name )`

```
/**
 * Gets a menu id by name
 * 
 * @param string $name The menu name
 * @return int|boolean The menu id or false if not found
 */
function wp_menu_id_by_name( $name ) {
    $menus = get_terms( 'nav_menu' ); 

    foreach ( $menus as $menu ) {
        if( $name === $menu->name ) {
            return $menu->term_id;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

### Let's use it

```
echo 'My Special Menu id is ' . wp_menu_id_by_name( 'My Special menu' );

// Outputs: My Special Menu id is 3
```

Answer (score 2):

I've used the `wp_get_nav_menu_object`. You can pass menu slug or name to it to get the menu object and then you can access the `term_id` from it. [Codex for wp_get_nav_menu_object](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_get_nav_menu_object/).

```
$menu_obj = wp_get_nav_menu_object(MENU_SLUG);
$menu_id  = $menu_obj ? $menu_obj->term_id : 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't use the right code, use this instead:

```
global $wpdb;

$tablename = $wpdb->prefix.'terms'; // use always table prefix
$menu_name = 'top-menu'; // menu name
$menu_id = $wpdb->get_results(
    "
    SELECT term_id
    FROM ".$tablename." 
    WHERE name= '".$menu_name."'
    "
);

// results in array 
foreach($menu_id as $menu):
    echo $menu->term_id;
endforeach;
```